# Hook Facebook Post Embed iframe load with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

When you use Facebook's Post Embed feature, you past in some code like this into your HTML:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/posts/1015145958723" data-width="466"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX/posts/10122337758390723">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX">Jayco</a>.</div></div>
```

Then, Facebook uses JavaScript to inject an iframe into the `<div class='fb-post'>` element, resulting in something like this:

```
<div class="fb-post ....>
  <span style="vertical-align: .....>
    <iframe name="f1b49ddc" width="550px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:post Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?......
       Facebook Post Embedded Here......
    </iframe>
  </span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use jQuery to hook when the iframe is fully loaded? I need to do some stuff on document load, but only after the iframe has loaded.

Comment: doesn't window (not document!) onload event works for that?

Comment: I think it typically works if your iframe is in your HTML but in this case, Facebook injects the iframe.

Comment: But have you tried it? If not working, you could still try to bind onload event for the iframe inside the window onload handler

Comment: Yes I've tried it and it doesn't work. I think that it's because jQuery's `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).ready()` are firing before the `iframe`'s are being created, since they are injected after the fact. Make sense?

Comment: the event i was talking was `$(window).on('load',function(){$('iframe').on('load',function(){handler});});`